# Products and shopping Rich Snippets appropriate for travel services?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets

Think about a travel site who allows their customers to book hotels, airport transfers, flights and excursions.

As you know, we can use [Rich Snippets](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) to get special search results on Google for our products. For example like below [Products and Shopping](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146750) category:

> [image: Google Search result: showing Review Rich Snippet for a Product]

Do you think Products and Shopping Rich Snippets would be appropriate for those kind of travel products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately none of those formats are suitable for what you do. What you're offering is a service and although each of the rich snippets formats support Products, services are really quite different things.

There's some discussion of the need for something on services on the [Microformats wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/service-formats)

> There is a need for a specific microformat dedicated to providing
>   detailed universal structure to services provided to businesses and
>   consumers.

It doesn't look like someone's actually done the work to define it though. There's no sign of it on the schema.org website either.

Comment: I see what you meant and it makes total sense. So, assume that I go ahead and apply those to my accommodation service page (hotels in this case). Do you thing search engines would pick them up?

Comment: If you get them right then they may pick them up. "though Google does not guarantee that markup on any given page or site will be used in search results." http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170

Comment: yeah, I know it is not for sure that they will be picked up but there are some properties which really fits into my situation. I just don't google to blackmail my site for that misconfiguration:)